# Validation Rule Language

Tags: validation-rule

I have a simple validation rule that should not be triggered when working as a system administrator. So the simplest version would be:

```
AND(
  $Profile.Name != "System Administrator",
  ...
)
```

However in one org I have to use the german version:

```
$Profile.Name != "Systemadministrator"
```

Why is that? What language setting is responsible for this behavior?

Comment: Something to do either with the selected Locale in the User's record, or the default locale for the overall org, I'd wager. Using a Custom Permission could make this a non-issue though. Is there a reason why you're not using a Custom Permission here?

Comment: @DerekF Not really. But I agree this is the better solution. I just wondered that it wasn't working as expected. I will check the locale though. Thanks!

Comment: Huh. So changing the user's locale does nothing. I won't try to change the org's locale though as for some reason I cannot reset my locale to "German (Germany, Euro)" now - it's not in the list. I'll make a sandbox for this test.

Comment: You could use VLOOKUP in Validation rules to compare against an object with all possible translations of `System Administrator` if you are looking to generalize this VR across all orgs